# User Authentication using linkedin

Tags: ios

i am trying to sign using linkedin.Once succesful login,i write following code.My problem is when i get acceses token i use same for api
 LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                          NSString *at=[[session accessToken] accessTokenValue];
                                          NSString *url=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json",at];
In response i get follwing
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unable to verify access token",
  "requestId": "XXFRO610RP",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1443599825188
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the access token to the request. Once the user is authorized and the permissions are assigned, try this.

```
 if ([LISDKSessionManager hasValidSession]) 

 {

 NSString *url=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address)&format=json"];


 [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:url
success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response) {

    // do something with response
    }
 error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
    // do something with error
   }];
]}
```